# "SQL Agent is not running" Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2017, sql-agent, ssrs-2017

I'm trying to do a schedule on Reporting Services. When I apply the configuration, it says to me that SQL Agent is not running and it needs that service to complete the operation.

But if I go to the services list, the SQL Agent Service is running. What's wrong then?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank's in advance

Edit: [This is the log generated when I try to schedule](http://jmp.sh/HD8mIgF)

Comment: I notice that I can't see the SSRS service in your screenshot, is it safe to assume it is running on a different server?

Comment: Actually is the same server (I've just added a pic with the Reporting Service)

Comment: Is it SQL Server 2017, per chance?

Comment: Yes, it's the 2017 one

Comment: That makes more sense. I'll admit, I've not used SSRS 2017 as yet; the set up is a little different to 2016 and prior as it's a separate installation. Apologies, but I don't have an answer for you at the moment. I do have a 2017 test environment, which, if i have a chance, I'll see if i can replicate on there. No promises I will get that chance though, however, hopefully someone else might have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Credentials for SQL Server agent as well as Reporting Services. It should be same otherwise it should contains proper rights. Check rights for
Reporting Services databases in SQL server also helps. Please feel to comment or add suggestions.

Comment: Both services uses Network Services to login. But the error still appears

Comment: Ok then seems no issue in services. Have you check "Reporting Services Configuration Manager" configuration? Is that working on same.

My suggestion is to add administration account credentials in Services and SSRS configuration. If it is not possible then use normal account with proper databases "ReportServer" rights and windows rights as well. Hope this will help :)

Comment: I've tried that, but the error still persists.

I've set the account SERVIDOR\Administrador (the admin account of the system) to SSRS Configuration Manager as Service Account and to Reporting and Agent Services to login with.

I'm really confused :S

Comment: Did you check log files? Check if any errors are highlighted in that file. If possible please share me that file. You will get it in this default location: %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\<SQL Server Instance>\Reporting Services\LogFiles

Comment: I've added on the end of the original question a link  to get the log file that's generated when I try to do a schedule.

Comment: Thanks David. I checked that log file and as per that issue is all indicating about SQL server agent. I also checked screenshot provided by yourself of services. As we can see there is no **SQL Server Agent Sevice** is available in existing system. You will get one tab named **SQL Server Agent** in SQL management studio as well. Is that showing in SSMS? Are you using Express version of SQL server? I think there is limited versions of SQL server which only provide SQL server agent. Please check and confirm.

Comment: Yep, the SQL Server Agent Service exists. You can't see in the screenshot because it's named in Spanish (Agente SQL Server) so it's on the top on the services list.

Comment: Ok then last thing you can do is to create some jobs like simple mail sending in SQL server agent from SSMS first, Just to make sure its working fine. If its working then restart that SQL agent from SSMS. In some weird situation, application server restart also works.